# Lack of motivation around the end of the year

Tags: words, terminology

Is there a term like 五月病 that is used to describe lack of motivation around the end-of-the-year / New Year?  I looked up 年末年始病 and 正月病, but I'm not sure if they are real terms or not.

My vacation starts in 2 days, and I have no motivation to work......

Answer (score 4):

I guess there's no word specific for 'lack of motivation before vacation' though I personally agree that I feel less motivation **before** vacation.

To an extent, 五月病 refers to the lethargy after a golden week (3-5 days of consecutive holidays), likewise, there's 正月ボケ for the lack of motivation (or more like 'unreadiness' for work) **after** the new year vacation is over.

I sometimes use お休みモード(/休暇モード/クリスマスモード) to describe things getting slower around vacation (e.g. responses to email/chat, esp. this time of the year from Western world). This should be understood in an appropriate context, but may be somewhat personal.

Happy holidays :)